# Can 'WebSite' be used inside 'ItemList'?

Tags: schema.org

I have a list of websites that are related to a particular topic. I am adding `ItemList` to the whole page and website inside `ListItem`.

In [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-features), the `WebSite` type is not mentioned, but it's there in [Schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/full.html). So can it be used like this or is there any other preferred way to do this?

**For topic page**

`ItemList`

- `ListItem` (`WebSite` schema inside)
- `ListItem` (`WebSite` schema inside)
- `ListItem` (`WebSite` schema inside)
- …

**For website page**

`WebSite` schema

- `name`
- `description`
- `url`
- …

Comment: What do you mean with "for SEO"? Do you ask if you get a rich result with this?

Comment: I want to provide structured data of list of websites for indexing and better search results.

Comment: I don’t understand -- how would/should this change the search results? Your question is fine if you ask how something specific can be marked up with Schema.org, but if you ask about SEO, you need to clarify what exactly you mean (see also: [Schema.org and SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/108333/17633)). Do you only want to know how to mark it up correctly with Schema.org? If yes, I’d suggest to edit out the SEO part.

Comment: Ok fine, Edited.

Comment: Have you tested it with the validation tool? What happened?

Comment: "In Google docs, the `WebSite` type is not mentioned": Not related to your question, but note that Google *does* make use of `WebSite` (for your own website): [Sitelinks Searchbox](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have an [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) with `WebSite` entries.

The [`itemListElement`](http://schema.org/itemListElement) property can take *every* Schema.org type as value. If the position inside the list is not important (i.e., the entries are not ranked), you don’t *have* to use `ListItem`, you could use `WebSite` directly instead.

To make sure that a consumer doesn’t mistakenly consider all the `WebSite` items to be about the current website:

- For the topic page, you could use:
  [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) `ItemList`
- For the website page, you could use:
  [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage) [`about`](http://schema.org/about)/[`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) `WebSite`
- From these `CollectionPage`/`ItemPage` items, you could point to your own `WebSite` with [`isPartOf`](http://schema.org/isPartOf).

Note that Google Search provides a feature that makes use of `ItemList` + `ListItem`: [Carousels](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings). But this doesn’t apply to lists with `WebSite` entries. So if you get errors/warnings in Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool, they might be related to this feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Website in an entity, it is a part of multiple topics and collections. Is this approach still valid? You can get more idea about data type from here (https://www.cybrhome.com/topic/engineering-blogs).

Comment: @AjeetLakhani: You mean if you can have the same `WebSite` in multiple `ItemList`s? Sure, it wouldn’t make sense to restrict this.