# Using Product Structured Data when not selling online

Tags: seo, structured-data

I'm currently working on a site that sells expensive but very niche products that have to be specified to a certain specification before being made to order. We will never sell these products to the public and we expect the people who buy them to know what they are looking for.

Is there any point using structured data in this case?

Comment: [Schema.org and SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/108333/17633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structured data is used to tell search engines the info about your website, pages, events, products, etc. that they would otherwise have to infer, or may not find at all. That markup, when implemented correctly, frequently (but not always) winds up as rich results for your site when it appears in SERPs. This markup also becomes more important the bigger the Internet of Things gets - after all, structured data is basically metadata.

If you don't care about rich results on your products in SERPs, you don't really need the structured data on those products. However, you might still want to include structured data on your website, for marketing and branding purposes: your "corporate" info, contact info, social links, locations served, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**[What is structured data?](https://yoast.com/seo-basics-what-is-structured-data/)**

> Structured data is code. It’s a piece of code that you can put on your
>   website. It’s code in a specific format, written in such a way that
>   search engines understand it. Search engines read the code and use it
>   to display search results in a specific way.

If you do not sell your products online (as you say in the title of your question), then the use of structured data is meaningless. You do not need to explain the search engines details about products that you do not sell.