# Does the order of my structured data effect SERP position?

Tags: rich-snippets, structured-data

When I look at structured data examples for rich results (regardless of Type) I notice that different websites have different priorities of the "properties".

Does the order of my structured data properties matter in determining SERP position?

---

As an example here are two recipe rich results from two different websites.
Both examples are for the same @type (recipe) (Strawberry Shortcake).

**Destination urls:**

Allrecipes Result:https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/8201/strawberry-shortcake/

Foodnetwork Result:https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/strawberry-shortcake-recipe3-1938695

**Google Query:**
https://www.google.com/search?q=recipe+for+strawberry+shortcake&oq=recipe+for+strawbe&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.8784j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

**Structured Data:**

AllRecipes is the first result (left to right). Their structured data is ordered as follows:

```
@type   
mainEntityOfPage    
name    
url 
headline    
description 
datePublished   
dateModified
```

Foodnetwork is the second result (left to right). Their structured data is ordered as follows:

```
@type   
url 
mainEntityOfPage    
recipeCategory  
recipeCategory  
recipeCategory  
image   
name
```

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! ***Does the order of my structured data effect SERP position?*** No. Content structure? Possibly. This may be the difference between the two sites. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of structured data properties can't effect rankings.  This is because [Google says](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/980902538865205248) structured data doesn't affect rankings at all.

For more information about how structured data actually affects SEO see: [Is Schema.org structured data (in Microdata, JSON-LD, or RDFa) relevant for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/108333/14543)