# How to validate microdata is improving the search ranking?

Tags: seo, microdata

I have recently updated our website FAQ section using microdata. Once the page was pushed into production, I used the following tools to validate my schema markup

1. Google Structured Data Tool
2. Rich snippets

The results are looking good. At this moment, I don't know whether Google has improved our search ranking or not? What other tests I can perform to validate?

Comment: Don’t use microdata. Use JSON-LD instead.

Comment: i understand, but JSON-LD is good if the data or FAQ's are not changing much. In our case it is changing very frequently, so we have gone down the microdata path. Though these techniques both are provided at google developer forums. What I want to understand is what other tests can I perform to see our ranking has improved. For microdata, is google structured data tool or rich snippets only way to verify?

Comment: That's a good reason to stick with microdata. If it helps maintenance. Google states that structured data has no direct influence on ranking. The only other test I can think of is to see if you get the FAQ rich snippets from real results. You can confirm this via the GSC Performance report set to filter Search Appearance by "FAQ rich results".

Answer (score 1):

Using microdata does not improve rankings.   You can't verify that it will help your rankings, because it won't.

At best, using structured data gives you rich snippets in the Google search results.  Getting rich snippets may improve your click through rate and make your site appear more attractive.  This may indirectly increase your rankings as Google may look at user-engagement as a ranking factor.

Using structured data may help search engines better understand what your site is about.  This could help them show your site for relevant queries and not show your site for irrelevant queries.

See [Schema.org and SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108333/schema-org-and-seo)